# How can I apply a jQuery plugin to a JavaScript DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A couple of days ago I had a question about the use of a library called select2,
that in the official documentation for its installation and use you have to obtain the element through jquery `$('.mySelect').select2();` my doubt is what it does exactly when you do this action `.select2();`(in a technical way) to the element and what would be the equivalent action doing it with `document.getElementById('mySelect')`.

Comment: Simply put, you can't. Select2 is a jQuery plugin and expects a jQuery object as its actor.

Comment: "doubt is what it does exactly when you do this action" — Lots of things. Read its source code to see what specifically. Explaining all the steps it takes in detail is too broad a topic to cover on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I mean in a technical way what it does `.select2();` in jquery, not what the library itself does, but the equivalence of the aforementioned action in javascript vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `jQuery-Plugin`. Underlying there is a function which has a reference to your selected element (`.mySelect`) in the `this` statement. Take a look here for more information https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0):

Select2 is based on Jquery, can't use Select2 without Jquery.

[Read More About this issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3652)